# StreamReader.ReadLine() reads line as empty when it isn't

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read data from a csv file:

```
    private static void ReadAnimalData(string file, Dictionary<string, Branch> branches)
    {
        string town = null;

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@file))
        {
            string line = null;
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                town = line;
            }
            Branch branch = branches[town];
            while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(',');
                char type = Convert.ToChar(line[0]);
                string name = values[1];
                int chipId = int.Parse(values[2]);
                string breed = values[3];
                string owner = values[4];
                string phone = values[5];
                DateTime vd = DateTime.Parse(values[6]);
                Console.WriteLine(type);

                switch (type)
                {
                    case 'D':
                        bool aggressive = bool.Parse(values[7]);
                        Dog dog = new Dog(name, chipId, breed, owner, phone, vd, aggressive);
                        branch.Dogs.Add(dog);
                        break;
                    case 'C':
                        Cat cat = new Cat(name, chipId, breed, owner, phone, vd);
                        branch.Cats.Add(cat);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Data file:

```
Kaunas
D,Reksas,823,Buldogas,Jonas,867424992,2015-07-24,TRUE
C,Morkus,658,Siamo,Antanas,865412654,2014-11-24
D,Keksas,456,Taksas,Petras,866612345,2014-12-01,FALSE
...
```

However, the following code doesn't work. It reads the first line as intended, but reading the second one leads to an error (`IndexOutOfRangeExeption`). The error happens because for some reason `reader.ReadLine()` reads the line as `""`. What might be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Could it be that the second line *is* actually empty, but you're looking at the file in Notepad++ or some other application that hides redundant whitespace characters?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Additionally, do you know what operating system produced your input data source?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You were right. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest to add     if (line == "") cotinue;    just to avoid blank lines.

Comment: Try making the read loop ignore whitespace lines `while (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(line = reader.ReadLine())) { .. }`

Comment: @YannickMotton That would make the loop exit on the first blank line, probably not what OP wants

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Hmm, indeed, didn't realize null indicates the EOF. Keep the while as is, and conditionally process if the string is `!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(...)`